# Recursively list all the files with path relative to the directory being scanned

Tags: bash

Let's say we have something like:

```
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/CONTENTS
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/opt
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/opt/source
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/opt/source/sm
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/opt/source/sm/LVHDoISCSISR.py
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/opt/source/sm/LVHDoHBASR.py
/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/verify_update
```

I want to get:

```
CONTENTS
opt/source/sm/LVHDoISCSISR.py
opt/source/sm/LVHDoHBASR.py
verify_update
```

I do have some options but I don like them:

- `cd /tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR; find . -name '*'` would add `./` before and worse would change 
  current directory.
- `ls` doesn't work well recursively

Note: I would prefer a single line solution, if possible :D

Answer (score 3):

With GNU find:

```
find /tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU find, at least, you can do this:

```
(cd /tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR; find . -type f -printf '%P\n')
```

The () causes it to run in a subshell so your cwd isn't affected. -type f matches only regular files, which is possibly better style than -name '*', but has slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, similar to the answer by @rici:

```
(cd /tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR; find * -type f -print)
```

That avoids the `-printf` that might be slightly (but maybe not noticably) less efficient, and which is a non-universal GNU extension - however it fails if you have any files/subdirectories that start with `.`.

You could also just post-process `find`s output:

```
find /tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR -type f -print | sed -e 's;^/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR/;;'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s globstar

startdir="/tmp/tmp.KVKc82GspR"
for file in "${startdir}"/**; do
    echo "${file/${startdir}}"
done
```

This will find all files in the directory and list them.  It is recursive.  I believe it will require bash 4 or higher.

If you want to see the files in your CURRENT directory:

```
shopt -s globstar
# the ls command has a 1 (one) as the first argument
ls -1d **
```

So this can be a one-liner like so:

```
shopt -s globstar ; ls 1d **
```